# Excel com-object via powershell

Tags: excel, csv, powershell, com

I am doing data output to csv file via powershell. Generally things goes well.

I have exported the data to csv file. It contains about 10 columns. When I open it with MS Excel it's all contained in first column. I want to split it by several columns programmatically via powershell(same GUI version offers). I could make looping and stuff to split the every row and then put values to appropriate cell but then it would take way too much time.

I believe there should be an elegant solution to make one column split to multiple. Is there a way to make it in one simple step without looping?

This is what I came up with so far:

PS, The CSV file is 100% FINE. The delimiter is ','

```
Get-Service | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation c:\1.csv -Encoding UTF8
$xl = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$xl.Visible = $true
$xl.DisplayAlerts = $False
$wb = $xl.Workbooks.Open('c:\1.csv')
$ws = $wb.Sheets|?{$_.name -eq '1'}
$ws.Activate()

$col = $ws.Cells.Item(1,1).EntireColumn
```

[image]

Comment: Does the file look as you would expect when you open it in a text editor like notepad? (i.e. comma seperated columns, line seperated rows). Not sure what datagridviews output looks like, I tend to use `Export-Csv` which Excel likes.

Comment: show us your csv file so we can reproduce it...

Comment: I have updated the original post. CSV file is not the reason at all. It has correct structure and all. Just when you open excel you would need to use an option to split column by specified delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get you the desired functionality; add to your code. Check out [the MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193593.aspx) for more information on TextToColumns.

```
# Select column
$columnA   = $ws.Range("A1").EntireColumn

# Enumerations
$xlDelimited     = 1
$xlTextQualifier = 1

# Convert Text To Columns
$columnA.texttocolumns($ws.Range("A1"),$xlDelimited,$xlTextQualifier,$true,$false,$false,$true,$false)
$ws.columns.autofit()
```

I had to create a CSV which had `"",""` as delimiter to test this out. The file with `","` was fine in excel.

```
# Opens with all fields in column A, used to test TextToColumns works
"Name,""field1"",""field2"",""field3"""
"Test,""field1"",""field.2[]"",""field3"""

# Opens fine in Excel
Name,"field1","field2","field3"
Test,"field1","field.2[]","field3"
```

**Disclaimer:** Tested with `$ws = $wb.Worksheets.item(1)`

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!